# R split a character string on the second underscore

Tags: regex, r, split

I have character strings with two underscores. Like these

```
c54254_g4545_i5454
c434_g4_i455
c5454_g544_i3
.
.
etc
```

I need to split these strings by the second underscore and I am afraid I have no clue how to do that in R (or any other tool for that sake). I'd be very happy if anyone can sort me out here.
Thank you
SM

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One way would be to replace the second underscore by another delimiter (i.e. space) using `sub` and then split using that.

Using `sub`, we match one or more characters that are not a `_` from the beginning (`^`) of the string (`^[^_]+`) followed by the first underscore (`_`) followed by one or characters that are not a `_` (`[^_]+`).  We capture that as a group by placing it inside the parentheses (`(....)`), then we match the `_` followed by one or more characters till the end of the string in the second capture group (`(.*)$`).  In the replacement, we separate the first (`\\1`) and second (`\\2`) with a space.

```
strsplit(sub('(^[^_]+_[^_]+)_(.*)$', '\\1 \\2', v1), ' ')
#[[1]]
#[1] "c54254_g4545" "i5454"       

#[[2]]
#[1] "c434_g4" "i455"   

#[[3]]
#[1] "c5454_g544" "i3"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c('c54254_g4545_i5454', 'c434_g4_i455', 'c5454_g544_i3')
```

Answer (score 5):

```
strsplit(sub("(_)(?=[^_]+$)", " ", x, perl=T), " ")
#[[1]]
#[1] "c54254_g4545" "i5454"       
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "c434_g4" "i455"   
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "c5454_g544" "i3"
```

With the pattern `"(_)(?=[^_]+$)"`, we split on an underscore that comes before a series of one or more non-underscore characters. That way we only need one capture group.

Comment: If this is not general, you don't need `sub`, `strsplit(x, '(_)(?=[^_]+$)', perl=TRUE)` as the pattern can be directly used to split. (+1).

Answer (score 2):

I did this. However, although it works there may be a 'better' way?

```
str = 'c110478_g1_i1'

m = strsplit(str, '_')
f <- paste(m[[1]][1],m[[1]][2],sep='_')
```